# How to reset or re-initialize a Jquery plugin being used on AJAX-updated links?

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using this plugin for adding arrow key navigation to a [website](http://firedev.com/jquery.keynav/#link)

Works great! However, sometimes my links are updated via AJAX and then the highlighting disappears. So I started re-initializing the plugin when my links were updated. I noticed this solved the problem, however now I had multiple copies of the plugin running, thus highlighting multiple buttons at once.

I know there isn't a 'built in' destory method in Jquery, but does anyone have any ideas on how to re-initialize a plugin or at least get rid of the old instance running.

You can see the source code of the [plugin on GitHub](https://github.com/firedev/jquery.keynav/blob/master/javascript/jquery.keynav.js)

The plugin code is simple and I believe what I am trying to achieve is simple as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you are using has an update function, call that function as soon as you get the ajax result back.
for example

```
var $keyNav = $('#navigation a').keynav();
```

and on ajax success

```
$keyNav.update();
```

I haven't tested this code but I think it will work.

Comment: Hmmmm. No dice. Any other ideas? I placed some alerts in there and it looks like the update function isn't receiving the call. Maybe a notation thing?

Comment: Even if there were a way to completely "kill" the object, that's fine. I simply want a new instance, but the old one keeps tagging along.

Comment: Ok. I got the update function to receive a call, but the highlight doesn't come back. So it looks like a new plugin initializing is t hebest option,but like I said, I can't get the old one to go away.